# hadoop 2.2.0 64-bit installing but cannot start

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.2.0 Cluster on the servers. For now all the servers are 64-bit, I download the Hadoop 2.2.0 and all the configuration files have been set up. When I am running ./start-dfs.sh, I got the following error:

```
13/11/15 14:29:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/hchen/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.namenode]
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s' have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
HotSpot(TM): ssh: Could not resolve hostname HotSpot(TM): Name or service not known
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
Java: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Java: Name or service not known
The authenticity of host 'namenode (192.168.1.62)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 65:f9:aa:7c:8f:fc:74:e4:c7:a2:f5:7f:d2:cd:55:d4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? VM: ssh: Could not resolve        hostname VM: Name or service not known
You: ssh: Could not resolve hostname You: Name or service not known
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
64-Bit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 64-Bit: Name or service not known
...
```

Beside the 64-bit, is there any other errors? I have finished the log in between namenode and datanodes without password, what do the other errors mean?

Comment: For searchability: this problem also applies to Hadoop 2.4.0 and Hadoop 2.4.1.

Answer (score 22):

Add the following entries to .bashrc where HADOOP_HOME is your hadoop folder:

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

In addition, execute the following commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 9):

The root cause is that the default native library in hadoop is built for 32-bit.
The solution

1) Setup some environment variables in `.bash_profile`. Please refer to https://gist.github.com/ruo91/7154697
Or

2) Rebuild your hadoop native library, please refer to http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html

Comment: welcome to SO. Please provide more details from mentioned links. It will help troubleshoot problem in case they become unavailable

Answer (score 4):

You also can export variables in hadoop-env.sh

```
vim /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

*/usr/local/hadoop* - my hadoop installation folder

```
#Hadoop variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 # your jdk install path
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

Comment: change export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib" to export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native"

Answer (score 2):

I think that the only problem here is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524886/error-in-starting-namenode-in-hadoop-2-4-1), so the solution is also the same:

Stop JVM from printing the stack guard warning to stdout/stderr, because this is what breaks the HDFS starting script.

Do it by replacing in your `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` line:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

with:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -XX:-PrintWarnings -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

([This solution](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/hadoop-java-hotspottm-execstack-warning/) has been found on [Sumit Chawla's blog](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/))

Comment: stack guard problem mostly happen on the x64 archetecture.

Comment: any idea about this error. WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the native library. Please see that its just a warning . Please export the hadoop variables mentioned above . That will work

Answer (score 0):

You have three issues:

1. " **Unable to load native-hadoop library**"  just as @Nogard said. His answer solves this problem.
2. "**The authenticity of host 'namenode (192.168.1.62)' can't be established.**" is because you have no ssh authentication. Do this:

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   scp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   your_install_user@192.168.1.62:/home/your_install_user/.ssh/`
3. "**sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s' have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
   HotSpot(TM): ssh: Could not resolve hostname HotSpot(TM): Name or service not known
   -c:** "

   Try this : edit your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` and put this into it:

   ```
   export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
   export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
   ```

   and `source .bash_profile` or `source .bashr` to make the change effective immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem & could not solve it after following all the above suggestions.

Finally understood that, the hostname configured and IP address is not assigned for the same.

My hostname was `vagrant` and it is configured in `/etc/hostname`. But I found that the IP address for the vagrant is not assigned in `/etc/hosts`. In `/etc/hosts` I found IP address for only `localhost`.

Once I updated the hostname for both `localhost` and `vagrant` all the above problems are resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_PREFIX` is properly set. I had this issue. Also, the ssh passwordless needs to be properly set up.