# Hadoop 2.2.0 : "name or service not known" Warning

Tags: hadoop, ssh

My aim is to run hadoop 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 12.4 . i was able to do it but when i run following command: 
***rushi@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-dfs.sh***

my dfs is starting namenode, scondarynamenode and also datanode but the problem is i am getting following Warning

```
rushi@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-dfs.sh    
14/01/24 12:05:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Starting namenodes on [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
    It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
    localhost]
    sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
    Java: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Java: Name or service not known
    library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
    warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
    which: ssh: Could not resolve hostname which: Name or service not known
    have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
    might: ssh: Could not resolve hostname might: Name or service not known
    You: ssh: Could not resolve hostname You: Name or service not known
    loaded: ssh: Could not resolve hostname loaded: Name or service not known
    Server: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Server: Name or service not known
    HotSpot(TM): ssh: Could not resolve hostname HotSpot(TM): Name or service not known
    have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
    64-Bit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 64-Bit: Name or service not known
    VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
    disabled: ssh: Could not resolve hostname disabled: Name or service not known
    VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
    stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
    The: ssh: Could not resolve hostname The: Name or service not known
    fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
    try: ssh: Could not resolve hostname try: Name or service not known
    guard.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard.: Name or service not known
    to: ssh: Could not resolve hostname to: Name or service not known
    now.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: Name or service not known
    will: ssh: Could not resolve hostname will: Name or service not known
    that: ssh: Could not resolve hostname that: Name or service not known
    stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
    the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
    you: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known
    -c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
    guard: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard: Name or service not known
    It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname It's: Name or service not known
    highly: ssh: Could not resolve hostname highly: Name or service not known
    fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
    recommended: ssh: Could not resolve hostname recommended: Name or service not known
    or: ssh: Could not resolve hostname or: Name or service not known
    the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
    library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
    link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: Name or service not known
    'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known
    with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
    <libfile>',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <libfile>',: Name or service not known
    it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: Name or service not known
    noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known
    with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
    '-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known
    localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/hadoop-rushi-namenode-ubuntu.out
    localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/hadoop-rushi-datanode-ubuntu.out
    Starting secondary namenodes [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
    It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
    0.0.0.0

]
```

What may be the problem and how to solve it?
Please help me

Comment: I see two problems here. One is related to native library other to hostname resolution. The hostname resolution may be due to JVM. I had `java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`. When I replaced it with `Oracle jdk1.8.0` it went away.

Comment: check you have installed the ssh and sshd?

Comment: https://github.com/vangj/vagrant-hadoop-2.3.0/wiki/HOWTO-resolve-OpenJDK-warning-on-disabled-stack-guard

Comment: follow the link if you want to remove the error relating to execstack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is same questions as given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011252/hadoop-2-2-0-64-bit-installing-but-cannot-start/20371832#20371832). It was just asked in other way round

After following this link still there is chance of getting following *Warning*

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

to resolve this warning follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos/19993403#19993403)

Answer (score 30):

One of the reason could be that default native library in Hadoop is built for 32-bit.

Add these lines to your .bashrc or .bash_profile:

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

$HADOOP_INSTALL is the location where you install Hadoop (generally it is /usr/local/hadoop).

or even there may be HADOOP_HOME instead of HADOOP_INSTALL.

Comment: What do you mean by "or even there may be HADOOP_HOME instead of HADOOP_INSTALL"? Do you mean "You might use HADOOP_HOME instead of HADOOP_INSTALL"? According to the [Apache documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop), "The value of HADOOP_HOME is automatically inferred from the location of the startup scripts." Perhaps you should just remove that last line from your answer.

Comment: its still not working for me... plese help [Posted the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24524886/error-in-starting-namenode-in-hadoop-2-4-1)

Comment: change this line to export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native". Otherwise problem will be there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only problem here is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20011252/2693875), so the solution is also the same:

Stop JVM from printing the stack guard warning to stdout/stderr, because this is what breaks the HDFS starting script.

Do it by replacing in your `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` line:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

with:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -XX:-PrintWarnings -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

([This solution](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/hadoop-java-hotspottm-execstack-warning/) has been found on [Sumit Chawla's blog](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/))

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly happen due to mis-configuration of .bashrc.

add these below code in your .bashrc file at the end.

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native"
#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

To remove the error about host. install the apache2 server. It will configure all the basic configuration of localhost.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.
```

check it on this url : http://localhost

read below the whole article to configure from beginning. 
http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php

Answer (score -1):

This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh

try start-yarn.sh