# Hadoop cluster does not start

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I just setup a hadoop cluster (namenode + one datanode). However, when I try to start hdfs I get the following error:

```
hadoop@namenode:/opt/hadoop-2.2.0$ start-dfs.sh
14/01/30 20:18:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
namenode]
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
You: ssh: Could not resolve hostname You: Name or service not known
64-Bit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 64-Bit: Name or service not known
Server: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Server: Name or service not known
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
loaded: ssh: Could not resolve hostname loaded: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
HotSpot(TM): ssh: Could not resolve hostname HotSpot(TM): Name or service not known
which: ssh: Could not resolve hostname which: Name or service not known
might: ssh: Could not resolve hostname might: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
guard.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard.: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
disabled: ssh: Could not resolve hostname disabled: Name or service not known
The: ssh: Could not resolve hostname The: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
will: ssh: Could not resolve hostname will: Name or service not known
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
try: ssh: Could not resolve hostname try: Name or service not known
Java: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Java: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
now.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: Name or service not known
guard: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard: Name or service not known
recommended: ssh: Could not resolve hostname recommended: Name or service not known
highly: ssh: Could not resolve hostname highly: Name or service not known
It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname It's: Name or service not known
that: ssh: Could not resolve hostname that: Name or service not known
you: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known
<libfile>',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <libfile>',: Name or service not known
link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: No address associated with hostname
noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known
it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: No address associated with hostname
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known
or: ssh: Could not resolve hostname or: Name or service not known
to: ssh: connect to host to port 22: Connection refused
namenode: starting namenode, logging to /opt/hadoop-2.2.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-namenode.out
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show your version of `start-dfs.sh`? How can you even execute this from the projects root dir? Maybe even `which start-dfs.sh` might be useful to know.

Comment: I can call start-dfs.sh from anywhere I want because I did a export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that this is a typical hadoop error on ubuntu. The solution to the problem can be found here: [Hadoop 2.2.0 : "name or service not known" Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326274/hadoop-2-2-0-name-or-service-not-known-warning)